# How to use and load JS helpers in Stimulus controllers in Rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I want to import and use functions from my `javascript/helpers/functions.js` file in my stimulus controllers.

I tried pinning it with:

```
# importmap.rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/helpers", under: "helpers"
```

Add it to the asset precompilation with:

```
# asset.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['helpers/*']
```

Also I've tried to import the file in `application.js` in different ways (not all at once):

```
// These are all the ways I tried to import the helpers folder in application.js
//= require_tree helpers
import "helpers"
import "./helpers"
```

In my Stimulus controller, I'm importing it like this

```
// javascript/controllers/select_controller.js
import {show, hideAll} from "helpers/functions";
```

As I understand this should work as importmap is mapping it to the helpers namespace but I also tried importing it like this:

```
// javascript/controllers/select_controller.js
import { show, hideAll} from "../helpers/functions"
```

I tried all kinds of variations of the above and it works fine locally in development but anytime I run the application in production the `helpers` folder gets not compiled or I get a 404 error.

How can I use JS helpers in Stimulus controllers the right way?

Answer (score 7):

**Found a solution to my own problem:**

```
# importmap.rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/helpers", under: "helpers"
```

I needed to import the specific helper file (function.js) in application.js:

```
// application.js
import "helpers/functions"
```

In the stimulus controller:

```
// javascript/controllers/select_controller.js
import {show, hideAll} from "helpers/functions";
```

Comment: What's inside the functions.js file? How do you state helper functions?

Comment: Just some helper functions I wanted to use in multiple controllers, for example:

`export function show(element) { element.classList.remove("hidden") }`